# Probability $P(Y_1 = 2 | Y_2 = 0)$ where $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2$ - $X1, \, X_2 \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ with uniform distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I'd like to know how to evaluate the probability $P(Y_1 = 2 | Y_2 = 0)$ where $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2$, where $X1, \, X_2 \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ have a uniform distribution so $P(X_1=k)=P(X_2=k) = 1/4$ (where $k \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$).

I can write:

$$
P(Y_1 = 2 | Y_2 = 0) = P(Y_1 = 2 | X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1) = ?
$$

---

EDIT: I'm interested in the case $X_1=X_2=1$; $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. I asked the question in the wrong way. The goal is to evaluate the following probability:

$$
P(Y_1 = 2 | X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1)
$$

Comment: Why don't you use the definition of conditional probability: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \inter B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: $Y_2 = 0$ means $(X_1, X_2) \in \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)\}$. Also, $(Y_1 = 2) \cap (Y_2 = 0)$ would mean $(X_1, X_2)$ is $(1, 1)$. So the conditional probability is $1/4$

Comment: Hello @BernardMasse is B the "event" $X_1=1, X_2=1$?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi. NO, $X1=2$ and $X2=2$ is also acceptable since $X1-X2=0$ and also 2 other cases. All but the one you quote will "go away" since then $X1+X2\neq2$

Comment: @BernardMasse I'm imposing $X_1=X_2=1$, so I'm interested in $P(Y_1 =2 | X_1=1, X_2=1)$. Which is the value of this probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\small\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y_1=2\mid Y_2=0)&=\mathsf P(X_1+X_2=2\mid X_1=X_2)&&\text{definition of }Y_1, Y_2\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1+X_2=2, X_1=X_2)}{\mathsf P(X_1=X_2)}&&\text{conditional probability}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1=1,X_2=1)}{\sum_{k=1}^4\mathsf P(X_1=k,X_2=k)}&&\text{law of total probability}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{1}{4}&&\text{independent & uniform discrete distributions}
\end{align}
$$